# What library to be to be used to avoid undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'

Tags: reference, undefined

I get undefined reference to `pthread_atfork' even after using pthread library. Is there any separate library for this?

Answer (score 2):

pthread_atfork() is part of the POSIX spec, so it should be there in the regular pthread library.

You may have to specify options to both the compiler & linker to build with pthreads. For example, with gcc/linux:

```
-pthread
       Adds support for multithreading with the pthreads library.  This option sets flags for both the
       preprocessor and linker.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are building for Android, then `pthread_atfork()` is not included in Bionic libc.  Check out this question for more information:

["undefined reference to pthread_atfork" while I was trying to port libpcsclite to Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12370970/undefined-reference-to-pthread-atfork-while-i-was-trying-to-port-libpcsclite-t)