# "undefined reference to pthread_atfork" while I was trying to port libpcsclite to Android

Tags: android, android-ndk

Android ndk told me `"undefined reference to pthread_atfork"` while I was trying to cross compile libpcsclite for Android

Actually I already knew there is no pthread_atfork function in Bionic library of Android (Android docs), but pthread_atfork must be called in pcsclite library. Is there any solution in this case?

Comment: Did you post your port anywhere? I'd be very interested to see smartcards working with Android!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `pthread_atfork()` was not [added to bionic libc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/4f086aeb4aa06e13079b7fec71a8178ceeacf318) until after android-10/v2.3.6/Gingerbread.  If you want to target older versions of Android, you either have to include [pthread-atfork.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/android-4.0.1_r1/libc/bionic/pthread-atfork.c) or the newer [pthread_atfork.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic.git/+/master/libc/bionic/pthread_atfork.cpp) in your project, or not use `pthread_atfork()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21
```

> this value defaults to the lowest API level supported by the NDK in use

in my Context,use android-9 default.

if you execute shell  below on your ${ANDROID-NDK} DIR,

```
 find_path=$1
 grep_str=$2

 SOS=`find ${find_path} -name *.so`
 for item in $SOS
 do
     echo ======= $item
     objdump -Tt $item |grep ${grep_str}
 done
```

`sh echo.sh . pthread_atfork`
the output:

```
======= ./platforms/android-9/arch-mips/usr/lib/libc.so
======= ./platforms/android-12/arch-x86/usr/lib/libc.so
00009420 g     F .text  0000000a              pthread_atfork
00009420 g    DF .text  0000000a  LIBC        pthread_atfork
```

you will found this message:`pthread_atfork` is defined on libc.so with android-12 but not android-9.

so when you cross compile with cmake or other tools,you need add `-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21` [just only gt android-9]

you can try this command with cmake

```
# on you project_root
mkdir build
cd build
cmake  -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/cross/github/jni/android-ndk-r14b/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a -DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=clang -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21   ..
```

Comment: please try to be more descriptive in your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Look at this: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.handhelds.android.ndk/15982

I believe function pthread_atfork is implemented in Bionic library (however, it's not documented).

I think all you have to do is to declare it to use it.

Usual caution: If you use undocumented methods, they may not work properly or may be deprecated in the future.

Comment: it's quite opposite , DOCS/CHANGES.html in the latest NDK  said  pthread_atfork is implemented , however, still told me "undefined reference to pthread_atfork" while cross-compiling.

Comment: it's the same problem as mine which was discussed in the website  you gave to me

Comment: I just looked in the Android Open Source Project (for OS 4.0.2). There is a file \bionic\libc\bionic\pthread-atfork.c and it has method pthread_atfork.

Comment: i also found the file pthread-atfork.c ,  not in my  source code ,but in this website [link](http://source-android.frandroid.com/bionic/libc/bionic/pthread-atfork.c).then i downloaded this c file ,and integrated it into the pcsclite source code. compiled successfully ! thank you . Victor.

Comment: @bob, where did you find the statement about `pthread_atfork()` being implemented? I can't find any reference to it.